# Undefined reference while including Crypto++ in QT project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, crypto++

I'm trying to use the Crypto++ library in my QT project (on windows), I'm a beginner in QT and I haven't find a solution yet.
So far, I compiled the library so that I have the *cryptlib.lib* file in the folder cryptopp/x64/Output/Release. Then, I added the whole cryptopp folder to my project folder and I wrote in my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/cryptopp/x64/Output/Release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/cryptopp/x64/Output/Release

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/cryptopp/x64/Output/Release/ -lcryptlib
win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/cryptopp/x64/Output/Release/cryptlib.lib
```

In my main.cpp file I wrote:

```
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/rijndael.h"
#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

    return 0;
}
```

Everything is recognized and I don't get any errors, but when I try to build (in release mode since I only included crypto++ in release) I get tons of undefined references to Crypto++ functions.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ensure the library you are linking is actually installed.

Comment: On some systems, the library is lined as "cryptopp" and on some systems "crypto++". Look for this when you go verify the installation. Oh, and you are not supposed to build it yourself, for a secure installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in windows, you don't need commands like sudo make install.
The "undefined reference" error message is a linker error, not a compiler error. It occurs when the linker cannot find the definitions for the functions or classes that were declared and used in your code. In your case, the linker is not finding the Crypto++ library's definitions.

In QT's output window, you can check the linker command and ensure it has correctly pointed to library directory and lib file. The correct linker command should like the following:

```
    g++ -I "path/to/cryptopp/include/" -L "path/to/cryptopp/lib/" myprogram.cpp -lcryptopp -g -o myprogram.exe
```

Note that The -lcryptopp option should come after your source file myprogram.cpp.